# How to separate year and months to days ? Create a view that counts the number of hires for each month

Tags: sql, sorting, select, group-by, count

Create a view that counts the number of hires for each month.  Sort the list by year then by month with its number of hires.

But the are output not combined into one rows because the "DAYS" is included. How to separate year and months to days ?

Anyone can improve my answer ?

This is my script

```
SELECT YEAR (hireDate) AS "YEAR ", MONTH (hireDate) AS "MONTH",  COUNT (hireDate) "hires for each month"
FROM employee
GROUP BY  hireDate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by the aggregate years and months.

```
SELECT YEAR (hireDate) AS "YEAR ", MONTH (hireDate) AS "MONTH",  COUNT (hireDate) "hires for each month"
FROM employee
GROUP BY  YEAR (hireDate), MONTH (hireDate)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I need to learn more about aggregate.

Comment: Glad it helped.  Here's a good tutorial to get yourself started. https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-grouping-sets/